# Simple proof of irrationality of e

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Is this reasoning correct?

Assume $e=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ are natural numbers
taking natural log on both sides
and using the fact that natural $\ln e = 1$. We come up with 
$1 = \ln\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)$.
Taking derivative on both sides
$0 = \large\frac{1}{\frac{p}{q}}$
taking $\frac{p}{q}$ to other side
results in  $0 = 1$ absurdity 
therefore $e=\frac{p}{q}$ is false
and hence $e$ is irrational.

What do you think guys?

Comment: You cannot differentiate, remember $p$ and $q$ are fixed numbers and not variables (it would be like saying $0 = \ln 1$, and by taking derivative you get $0 = \frac1 1 = 1$).

Comment: Differentiation makes non sense at all in this case. Try to use the series expansion of $e$ to prove $e$'s irrationality.

Comment: @user148329 : No, $p$ is a fixed (albeit unknown) number here, it can only have one value even if you don't know this value.

Comment: Now what about 3? Following your example, 3 = p/q implies 0 = ln (3) which is absurd, so 3 = p/q is false and hence 3 is irrational.

Comment: thanks guys I got excited by just seeing the result after 5 minutes of labor. I think one can do the differentiation however it would result in  0 = 0 since both sides of the equations are just constants and hence tells nothing about e

Comment: Try the same with $2$ in place of $e$ and $\log_2$ in place of $\ln$ :)

Comment: Looking for a working proof: have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational?

Comment: Remember, differentiation is something you do to *functions*, not to *numbers*. It is easy to get sloppy and write `5` when what is meant is `the function f(x) that equals 5 for all x`. The latter you can differentiate to get "the function f(x) that is equal to zero for all x". The former -- the number 5 -- you cannot differentiate to get the number 0.

Comment: Notice how your proof did not use the fact that p or q are integers. That's a surefire way to know that there's something wrong with the proof. In general, if you make an assumption, and don't use it the proof is no different than if the assumption were excluded.

Answer (score 21):

> Is this reasoning correct?

**No.** The differentiation part makes no sense. Consider doing the same thing with $e = C$ for some constant $C$. We would prove that $e$ in fact is not a number at all. This would mean that a huge number of mathematical papers would have to be revoked, and mathematical research would really take a huge blow.

And we don't want that.

Comment: Well, we DO want that if it were true, or yielded a useful branch of mathematics for us to research. But if it's wrong, or an extraneous solution, then I completely agree, we don't want to invalidate a few thousand years of research for no good reason. =)

Answer (score 6):

Before differentiating, you actually come up with $1 = \ln e$. So what are you taking the derivative with respect to? $e$? I'm sure you know that differentiating with respect to a constant doesn't make sense. ;-)

Comment: Or more precisely, "what function are you deriving?".